# Is it possible to create a permanent python server with docker?

Tags: python, docker

First of all, I would like to say that I am starting with dockworkers and I don't know if what I am asking for is feasible.
I would like to create a docker container to occasionally run python scripts on it with the same instance. 
I first oriented myself towards an API approach, but it doesn't suit me because I have scripts in different python versions, and I don't want to develop several APIs (one per container).

Is there a way to simply run scripts remotely on a container?

Thank you in advance!

Adrien

Comment: docker exec -it <containerName> <shellPath> For instance docker exec -it myContainer bash

Comment: What are you hoping to get from Docker here?  It is a more complicated setup than, say, Python virtual environments, and you can't use it this way without also having unrestricted root-level access to the system.

Comment: Docker's official [Get Started, Part 2: Containers](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) tutorial is pretty much required reading and runs through the process of building and running a custom Docker image, in Python even.  This is the "standard" way to use Docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your docker container, you can install the python versions that you want and then you could run your scripts using different python versions from the docker container.

1. First, you have to make a docker image with all your desired
   versions (for the sake of example, let's called it example_image).
2. For a specific python version you can use:

   docker run --rm -v `<path_to_your_py_file_directory>`:/app  example_image `<your_pthon_version>` /app/`<your_py_file>`

What you are doing at point 2: you are mapping the desired directory (that contain your .py files) to your docker container, so your desired directory is inside the docker container and now you can use any installed version of python to run your python script.

By using --rm you make sure that you are not wasting your resources and you are using a docker container as long as you need to test ('occasionally' as you mention).

Having the docker image you can say that your test tool is permanent.

For example (from terminal), I have a docker image with pyhton3 installed:

```
echo "print('is ok')" > test.py 
docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/app  my_ubuntu_image python3 /app/test.py
#output: is ok
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run commands inside already-running containers with [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/).

```
docker exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARG...]
```

To figure out the name/ID of your container, you can use `docker ps`

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by "simple".
First of all you will need a master process which monitior scripts process because docker container are made to run one specific process, not multiple.
Then you will need a way to trigger script excecution.
To do this easily, I suggest to use the web framework Flask (https://palletsprojects.com/p/flask/). You could put one script by url path and use the subprocess module to run them in the background.